# Linear Algebraic Group acting on the co-ordinate ring

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups

Let $G$ be a linear algebraic group and let $C[G] = C[x_1,...,x_n] / I(G)$ denote the coordinate ring of $G$.

(Note that $I(G)$ is the ideal containing all those polynomials in $C[x_1,...,x_n]$ of which elements of $G$ are the common zeroes.)

Now, we the action of $C$- points of $G$ on $C[G]$ is defined by : 
          $$ G_C \times C[G] \to C[G]$$
          $$(x,f(y)) \mapsto f(x^{-1}y) $$

I am not able to see the condition $x_1.(x_2.f) = (x_1.x_2).f$ being satisfied by this. Please help me in realising that this indeed is a group action. Thank you !

Comment: I recently worked through the details of this in Humphreys, and i determined it to be correct.  I will have a look at this in the next few hours.

Comment: Thank you ! I am looking forward for it ! Please give a hint or anything if you have in mind !

Comment: See my comment on the given answer for how the derivation goes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When evaluating $x_1\cdot(x_2\cdot f)(y)$, it's tempting to write $x_1\cdot(f(x_2^{-1}y))$ which I think is where the confusion comes from, but this doesn't make sense as $f(x_2^{-1}y)$ is a scalar. Instead, we have $x_2\cdot f\in C[G]$, so letting $x_1$ act on this function,
$$
(x_1\cdot(x_2\cdot f))(y)=(x_2\cdot f)(x_1^{-1}y)=f(x_2^{-1}x_1^{-1}y)=f((x_1x_2)^{-1}y)=((x_1x_2)\cdot f)(y)
$$
hence $x_1\cdot(x_2\cdot f)=(x_1x_2)\cdot f$.

Comment: I do not follow how that $f(x^{-1}y)$ is a scalar. I feel that it is also an element of $C[G]$, i.e , a polynomial. Can you please elaborate your point to help me out !

Comment: @JagdeepSingh If $V$ is an affine variety, ususally $C[V]$ is identified as functions from $V\to k$, $k$ being the underlying field. So $f$ is a polynomial, but if you actually plug in $x^{-1}y\in G$, you end up with an element of $k$. Maybe more clearly, if you denote $g=x_2\cdot f\in C[G]$, then $(x_1\cdot(x_2\cdot f))(y)=(x_1\cdot g)(y)=g(x_1^{-1}y)=(x_2\cdot f)(x_1^{-1}y)=\cdots$,